# Serve a folder different from the static directory in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to serve a static template using Django whose static files paths have been defined relative to that folder.

eg. I have my directory structure as

```
olx
--static
--fonts
--olx files
--index.html
```

I'm trying to serve `index.html` along with the static files. In my `index.html` I'm giving the path to static files like `<img src="static/1.jpg"/>`. If I open the index.html file directly on my computer it works.

I'm deploying it using Django as follows

```
url(r'^olx/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='olx/index.html'), name='olx'),
```

The template is hosted but the static files do not get hosted. How can I host the entire folder so that the static files work?

I have my STATICFILES_DIRS and STATIC_ROOT for the rest of my project set up and it works fine. I just need to figure out how I can host static files different from the main static directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that when you use relative paths in a link, it is the browser that resolves them - and it does so relative to the URL you are currently on, not the file path on the server (which it knows nothing about). Do if you are serving your template at "olx/", any relative links will be at " olx/...". It is therefore up to you to configure your web server to serve the relevant static files at that URL.

To be honest though I don't know why you would want to do this. Put all your static files in one place, using subdirectories if you want (which is what collectstatic will do anyway), and serve them under that u single URL.

Comment: There are cases where this is required by some companies to verify domain ownership by placing files in specific paths such as the root, or `.well-known` I'm currently trying to figure this out.